# Duplicates when using PyMongo update_one()

Tags: python, flask, pymongo, flask-restful

I'm creating a basic RESTFUL API using `flask_restful` and `python3`.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

client = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://xxx:password@fm-nz8t3.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites'
                     '=true&w=majority')

db = client['ERP']
users = db['users']


class Visit(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        user_count = int(users.find_one({})['users'])
        new_count = user_count + 1
        new_id = db.users.update_one({'users': user_count}, {'$set': {'users': new_count}})
        return 'User ID: {}'.format(new_count)


api.add_resource(Visit, '/')
```

The idea is to count how many users have "visited" my website. I do that by simply incrementing a variable bases on the previous `user_count`.

My **problem** is that my `users` field gets incremented by `two` and not by `one`, whenever I access my REST API on localhost `127.0.0.1:5000`.

If I run this directly:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)

client = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://xxx:password@fm-nz8t3.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites'
                     '=true&w=majority')

db = client['ERP']
users = db['users']
user_count = int(users.find_one({})['users'])
new_count = user_count + 1
new_id = db.users.update_one({'users': user_count}, {'$set': {'users': new_count}})
```

My `users` field DOES the job correctly, which increments the users field by one and **NOT** two.

Is there something I'm missing when using the inheriting from the `Resource` class? As I think that is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your error; but I might encourage you to refactor your code as follows to update using the `_id` field which is somewhat safer, especially if you errantly end up with more than one record in the collection:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

client = MongoClient() # Add in connection string as needed

db = client['ERP']
users = db['users']
users.insert_one({'users': 0})

class Visit(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        user_record = users.find_one({})
        user_count = int(user_record.get('users'))
        new_count = user_count + 1
        db.users.update_one({'_id': user_record.get('_id')}, {'$set': {'users': new_count}})
        return 'User ID: {}'.format(new_count)

api.add_resource(Visit, '/')

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```